# Connect Jenkins to GCP container registry

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform, jenkins-plugins, google-container-registry

I'm trying to connect jenkins to container registry on GCP.
I follow some examples but I'm blocked on a simple and stupid thing.

I have this stage in my jenkins file :

```
    stage('Push image') {
      docker.withRegistry('https://eu.gcr.io', 'gcr:[my-credentials]') {
        app.push("${env.BUILD_NUMBER}")
        app.push("latest")
      }
}
```

But I don't have any idea which credential put there...

I try to create on GCP -> API&Service -> Credentials -> Create Credential -> Service Account Key

Download the json and add it to Jenkins, on piplene field I use: name of project, credential id, and so on, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I found a solution.

- First of all you have to stop the Instance.
- Open the instance settings
- Edit the Instance
- At the end of the list of settings change the Cloud API access Scopes : give access to the resource that you need.

[image]